# Best way to create an SQL Server DB in AWS using Terraform?

Tags: sql-server-2005, terraform-provider-aws

To Devs, I am trying using the following:

```
   enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports        =  var.enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports
   create_cloudwatch_log_group            = var.create_cloudwatch_log_group
   cloudwatch_log_group_retention_in_days =  var.cloudwatch_log_group_retentions
   cloudwatch_log_group_kms_key_id        =  var.cloudwatch_log_group_kms_key
```

to create a SQL server DB on AWS using Terraform but am not able to create it with logging and encryption capability. But it does not work. Any ideas this? Thanks,